# getting freeMemory based on Runtime memory methods behaving Very wierd

Tags: java, hibernate, memory-management, jvm, runtime

I am using Runtime's memory approximation methods to do some memory usage analysis. I have created the following method for approximating amount of freeMemory in JVM at a given time :

```
private static long getFreeRuntimeMemory(){
    long usedMem, freeMem;

    usedMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    freeMem = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() - usedMem;
    //System.out.println("used "+ usedMem+ " free "+ freeMem);
    return freeMem;
}
```

I call this method two times - at the first line of my main method , and at the last line of my main method. In midst of these two calls , i do some hibernate based DB retrieving.

What is weird is that the return value of this method is smaller for the first call . How can that be? I did create some objects and they should not be deallocated before the main ends.

Comment: 1,) max memory is not necessarily a constant 2.) the values might change right between the three method calls and hence are not guaranteed to be consistent 3.) there might be unused objects on the heap before the first call which have been freed before the second call.

Comment: #1)Seems to be constant in my case, isn't the max memory fixed before JVM is launched?
#2, 3) - After some research of my own, this does make sense..

Comment: Whether max memory is fixed, is implementation dependent.